# Deleting items that have the place swapped around in a returned list

Tags: python, list

My function takes a number, and a list of numbers.

If 2 numbers in the list add up to the original number, in the form `[Num1, Num2]`.

Now I don't want any "duplicates" i.e. I only want `[4, -7]` returned and not `[4, -7], [-7, 4]`.

```
def pairs(n, num_list):
    newest_list = []
    for j in range(len(num_list)):
        for i in range(len(num_list)-1):
            if num_list[j] + num_list[i+1] == n:
                newest_list.append([num_list[j], num_list[i+1]])
    return newest_list
```

Now I'd like a hint rather than code posted, a simple.
My question is:

Do I have the ability to do that within my code, and if so, a hint would be great, or will I need to define another function to do that for me?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have the ability to do that within your code.

A hint to complete this would be to think about at what point in your code it makes sense to stop searching for further matches and to return what you've found. Let me know if that's too cryptic!

Answer (score 0):

You can still do that in your current code by simply appending these two numbers into a Set. For more info, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) will help you.

Comment: Is there a way to take the elements out of a set, and put them in the format of [num1, num2] into a list?

Comment: @RonaldB Yes.. So let's say you have this set `my_set = set([1,2,3,4])`. To convert it back to a list you simply have to this `my_list = list(my_set)`

Answer (score 0):

When adding a pair `[a, b]` to the result list, sort the pair, then see if it's in the result list.  If so, don't add it.

Also, consider using a [Python set](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set).

Answer (score 0):

if you have 2 lists l1, and l2 where:

```
l1=[1,2]
l2=[2,1]
```

If you convert them to sets, you can compare them and they will evaluate to **True** if they have the same elements, no matter what the order is:

```
set(l1) == set(l2) # this evaluates to True
```

In your if condition, before appending the numbers, you can check if the set `set([num_list[j], num_list[i+1]])` is already in `newest_list`.

I am tempted to write some code, but you said not to, so I'll leave it here :p

Comment: OP is storing tuples in `newest_list` not sets

Comment: @smac89 that is why i wrote set(l1)==set(l2) instead of writing l1=l2

Answer (score 0):

You can leave your code the way it is, but before you return the list, you can [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) the list with a predicate that the pair `[a,b]` is only accepted if pair `[b,a]` is not in the list